# Centre of a simple algebra is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, noncommutative-algebra

> How can one show that the centre of simple algebra is a field?

I have tried it and proved that the inverse exists for every element of centre but cannot prove that inverse of every element belongs to centre. Please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $ab=ba$ and $a^{-1}$ exists, then $a^{-1}b=a^{-1}(ba)a^{-1}=a^{-1}(ab)a^{-1}=ba^{-1}$.